# Smooth background image css transition with dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

To change the background of a DIV im using CSS transitions and jQuery:

```
var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/1000x1000',
  'http://placehold.it/999x999',
  'http://placehold.it/888x888',
];
target.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[bii] + ')');
```

**CSS**

```
#target, #target-cached {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

This works but the transition is very sluggish the first time it iterates the array because it is trying to animate when the images is still downloading. After the images is already downloaded the transition animation is very smooth.

[Take a look of this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8rwbk6cn/)

How can I prevent the transition if the images is not yet loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exemple with this light plugin :backstretch http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ by Scott Robbin. It works well in your fiddle exemple :)

```js
var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/1000x1000',
  'http://placehold.it/999x999',
  'http://placehold.it/888x888',
];

var target = $('#target');
var target2 = $('#target-cached');
var bii = 1;
var maxBii = 3;

target.backstretch(images[0]+ '?r=' + Math.random(),{duration: 3000, fade: 750});

target2.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[0] + ')');
setInterval(function() {
  target.backstretch(images[bii]+ '?r=' + Math.random(),{duration: 3000, fade: 750}); 
  target2.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[bii] + ')');
  bii++;
  if (bii >= maxBii) bii = 0;
  console.log(bii);
}, 1500);
```

```css
#target, #target-cached {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
Always new images
<div id="target">

</div>
<br />
<br />
Cached images
<div id="target-cached">

</div>
```